# Query Function Order by problem Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I already have the first part of the query ready, But I would like to order it with the newest date first. Can you please help!

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:I, "
SELECT D, -1 * SUM(I)
  GROUP BY D
  LABEL -1 * SUM(I) 'Balance Diario'
  FORMAT D         'yyyy-MMM-dd',
        -1 * SUM(I) '$#,##0.00'
")
```

Comment: Can you please share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this were you looking for?

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:I, "
SELECT D, -1 * SUM(I)
  GROUP BY D
  ORDER BY D DESC
  LABEL -1 * SUM(I) 'Balance Diario'
  FORMAT D          'yyyy-MMM-dd',
        -1 * SUM(I) '$#,##0.00'
")
```

Put more `ORDER BY D ASC`or`DESC`

`DESC` is to reverse the order